# Код написан и полностью правильно у всех работает а у меня нет в чем проблема?

Tags: python-3.x, windows

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот код:

````
import os
import asyncio
os.chdir(r'c:\qq891')
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='>')

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as', self.user)

    async def on_message(self, message):
        # don't respond to ourselves
        if message.author == self.user:
            return

        if message.content == 'ping':
            await message.channel.send('pong')

client = MyClient()
client.run('тут токен') ```

**Ввожу в cmd команду для запуска кода и ничего не происходит**
````

Answer (score 0):

ахахахха ошибка было в том что вместо os.chdir(r'c:\Users\qq891\Documents') я указал os.chdir(r'c:\qq891')